# something that doesn't fit us

Tags: word-request

What is particular 'verb' for the situation when one's footwear doesn't fit his foot and his foot comes out of the footwear again and again? 
Do we say:

> The shoe is getting out again and again.

Or do we say:

> The foot is getting out of shoe again and again.

Comment: Why not "My foot keeps coming out of my shoe"?

Answer (score 3):

You would probably say either "The shoe keeps coming off." or "The shoe keeps falling off."